# What causes waiting for localhost when refreshing web page

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, localhost

When I first load my HTML5 with ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.21, the click events work.  When I refresh the web page, one of the click events stops working (the identify task)  I have tried setting the click event in either the map.on("load"...) and the map.on("layers-add-result"...).  It doesn't matter.

Will the map.on("load"...) conflict with the map.on("layers-add-result"...)?
I am using ArcGISDyanicMapServiceLayer to load multiple map service layers.

On a page refresh in a web browser, why doesn't the map.on("layers-add-result"...) not run again?  I set up an alert to see if it got there on a refresh.

Is it an asynchronous issue?  I tried controlling the timing by using callbacks, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Here's the beginning of my code:

```
    parser.parse();
//This sample may require a proxy page to handle communications with the ArcGIS Server services. You will need to
//replace the url below with the location of a proxy on your machine. See the 'Using the proxy page' help topic
//for details on setting up a proxy page.
esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;

esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

gsvc = new GeometryService("https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

var geometryService = new GeometryService("http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");

clickedPointsArr = [];
var activetext = "off";

//esriConfig.defaults.io.corsDetection = false;

undoManager = new UndoManager();

//hook up undo/redo buttons

$("#undo").on("click", function () {
    undoManager.undo();
});
$("#redo").on("click", function () {
    undoManager.redo();
});

// layer indexes in the map services
var indexPoint_StormwaterOuterZoom = 34;
var indexPoint_StormwaterMiddleZoom = 35;
var indexPoint_StormwaterCloseUpZoom = 36;
var indexPoint_ControlPts = 1;
var indexPoint_FiberPts = 9;
var indexPoint_ReferencePts = 11;
var indexPoint_SchoolBusStopsOSPI = 19;
var indexPoint_AvistaPoleStructure = 28;
var indexLine_PriorityArray = 13;
var indexLine_RoadSegments = 38;
var indexLine_MajorRdsCitySt = 40;
var indexLine_Waterlines = 44;
var indexLine_Railroad = 41;
var indexPoly_NoTrucks = 32;
var indexPoly_CountyBdry = 13;
var indexPoly_Parcels = 53;
var indexPoly_MuniBdry = 83;
var indexPoly_Waterbody = 27;

var aerialURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/CurrentImagery/MapServer";
var aerialZoomURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/1_564_Dynamic/MapServer";

var customExtentAndSR = new esri.geometry.Extent(2380210.76526192, 109581.35051693, 2582107.45873931, 404235.534501359, new esri.SpatialReference({ "wkid": 2926 }));
var countyLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
var aerialLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(aerialURL, {
    id: "aerialLayer",
    visible: false
});

var pointsURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/PublicWorks/PublicWorksQueriesPoints/MapServer";
var linesURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/PublicWorks/PublicWorksQueriesLines/MapServer";
var polygonsURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/PublicWorks/PublicWorksQueriesPolygons/MapServer";

var aerialLayerZoom = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(aerialZoomURL, {
    id: "aerialLayerZoom",
    visible: false
});

var tilesLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(" http://gis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/Engineering/SectionMosaic/MapServer", {
    //var tilesLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://GISMO3.spokanecounty.org:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Engineering/SectionMosaic/MapServer", {
    id: "tilesLayer",
    visible: false
});

var pointsLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(pointsURL, {
    id: "pointsLayer",
    visible: true
});
var linesLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(linesURL, {
    id: "linesLayer",
    visible: true
});
var polygonsLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(polygonsURL, {
    id: "polygonsLayer",
    visible: true
});

var connects;
var refPtsLyr = 11;
var parcelslLyr = 53;
var aerialLayerInfoID = 91;
var aerialLayerInfoIDText = '"' + aerialLayerInfoID + '"';
var sectionmapsLayerInfoID = 149;
var sectionmapsLayerInfoIDText = '"' + sectionmapsLayerInfoID + '"';
var SWstructuresLayerInfoID = 128;
polygonsLayer.setImageFormat("png32");
polygonsLayer.setImageTransparency(true);

//Default values for Draw Tool
var TransVal = 1;
var MyThickness = 3;
var MyFontSize = 12;
var red = 0;
var green = 0;
var blue = 0;
var newColor = [red, green, blue, TransVal]

var myPointsLayer = "Points";
var myLinesLayer = "Lines";
var myPolygonsLayer = "Polygons";
var defaultPoints = true;
var defaultLines = true;
var defaultPolygons = true;
var myPointsArray = [];
var myLinesArray = [];
var myPolygonsArray = [];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RPWebService.asmx/GetFCLayerProfileVisibleLayers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"servicelayer":"' + myPointsLayer + '"}',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        if (obj == "Points NoResults;No Results Found") {
            defaultPoints = true;
            myPointsArray = [defaultVisiblePoints];
            //pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePoints]);
        }
        else {
            defaultPoints = false;
            myPointsArray = [obj];
            //pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([obj]);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Unable to load Map Profile: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
        myPointsArray = [defaultVisiblePoints];
        //pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePoints]);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RPWebService.asmx/GetFCLayerProfileVisibleLayers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"servicelayer":"' + myLinesLayer + '"}',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        if (obj == "Lines NoResults;No Results Found") {
            defaultLines = true;
            myLinesArray = [defaultVisibleLines];
            //linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisibleLines]);
        }
        else {
            defaultLines = false;
            myLinesArray = [obj];
            //linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([obj]);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Unable to load Map Profile: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
        defaultLines = true;
        myLinesArray = [defaultVisibleLines];
        //linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisibleLines]);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RPWebService.asmx/GetFCLayerProfileVisibleLayers",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"servicelayer":"' + myPolygonsLayer + '"}',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        if (obj == "Polygons NoResults;No Results Found") {
            defaultPolygons = true;
            myPolygonsArray = [defaultVisiblePolygons];
            //polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePolygons]);
        }
        else {
            defaultPolygons = true;
            myPolygonsArray = [obj];
            //polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([obj]);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Unable to load Map Profile: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
        defaultPolygons = true;
        myPolygonsArray = [defaultVisiblePolygons];
        //polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePolygons]);
    }
});

map = new Map("map", {
    extent: customExtentAndSR
});

//home button
var home = new HomeButton({
    map: map
}, "HomeButton");
home.startup();

//scalebar
var scalebar = new Scalebar({
    map: map
});

map.on("load", function () {
    toolbar = new Draw(map);
    toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
    //toolbar.on("draw-complete", addMeas);
    editToolbar = new Edit(map);
    pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([myPointsArray]);
    linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([myLinesArray]);
    polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([myPolygonsArray]);
    map.on("click", function (evt) {
        editToolbar.deactivate();
    });
    createMapMenu();
    createGraphicsMenu();
    map.reposition();
    map.resize();

    buildLayerList();
    firstPrint();
    // set up identify task click event
    connects = on(map, "click", executeIdentifyTask);
});

map.on("layers-add-result", function () {
    // test to see if sub-layers have been set as visible
    for (var j = 0; j < map.layerIds.length; j++) {
        var layer = map.getLayer(map.layerIds[j]);
        alert(layer.id + ' ' + layer.opacity + ' ' + layer.visible + ' ' + layer.visibleLayers);
    }
    // add legend
    legendDijit = new Legend({
        map: map,
        layerInfos: [{
            layer: polygonsLayer,
            hideLayers: [indexPoly_CountyBdry, indexPoly_MuniBdry],
            title: " ",
            respectCurrentMapScale: true
        },
        {
            layer: linesLayer,
            hideLayers: [indexLine_PriorityArray],
            title: " ",
            respectCurrentMapScale: true
        },
        {
            layer: pointsLayer,
            hideLayers: [indexPoint_ControlPts, indexPoint_FiberPts, indexPoint_ReferencePts, indexPoint_SchoolBusStopsOSPI],
            title: " ",
            respectCurrentMapScale: true
        }]
    }, "legendDiv");
    legendDijit.startup();
});

map.on("extent-change", function () {
    //alert("visible layers for points = " + pointsLayer.visibleLayers);
    var tempArray1, tempArray2, tempArray3 = [];
    tempArray1 = (getVisibleLayersPoints());
    if (tempArray1.length) {
        pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers(tempArray1);
    }                   
    tempArray2 = (getVisibleLayersLines());
    if (tempArray2.length) {
        linesLayer.setVisibleLayers(tempArray2);
    }
    tempArray3 = (getVisibleLayersPolygons());
    if (tempArray3.length) {
        polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers(tempArray3);
    }
    $('#divScale').text("Scale: " +  number.format(map.getScale(), { places: 0 }));
});

map.addLayers([aerialLayer, aerialLayerZoom, tilesLayer, polygonsLayer, linesLayer, pointsLayer]);
```

Comment: Try putting the code starting from map.on("layers-add-result"... to map.addLayers(....  inside of map.on("load"

Comment: Also could be a timing issue. Where is executeIdentifyTask defined? Is it before map.on("load.. if not, then that could be a possible reason.

Answer (score 1):

i think, you getting your ajax query's response after map onload so you need ajax query move to map onload function.

maybe do not add layer before map loading. i am not sure.

so finally code here :

```
    parser.parse();
//This sample may require a proxy page to handle communications with the ArcGIS Server services. You will need to
//replace the url below with the location of a proxy on your machine. See the 'Using the proxy page' help topic
//for details on setting up a proxy page.
esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;

esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

gsvc = new GeometryService("https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

var geometryService = new GeometryService("http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");

clickedPointsArr = [];
var activetext = "off";

//esriConfig.defaults.io.corsDetection = false;

undoManager = new UndoManager();

//hook up undo/redo buttons

$("#undo").on("click", function () {
    undoManager.undo();
});
$("#redo").on("click", function () {
    undoManager.redo();
});

// layer indexes in the map services
var indexPoint_StormwaterOuterZoom = 34;
var indexPoint_StormwaterMiddleZoom = 35;
var indexPoint_StormwaterCloseUpZoom = 36;
var indexPoint_ControlPts = 1;
var indexPoint_FiberPts = 9;
var indexPoint_ReferencePts = 11;
var indexPoint_SchoolBusStopsOSPI = 19;
var indexPoint_AvistaPoleStructure = 28;
var indexLine_PriorityArray = 13;
var indexLine_RoadSegments = 38;
var indexLine_MajorRdsCitySt = 40;
var indexLine_Waterlines = 44;
var indexLine_Railroad = 41;
var indexPoly_NoTrucks = 32;
var indexPoly_CountyBdry = 13;
var indexPoly_Parcels = 53;
var indexPoly_MuniBdry = 83;
var indexPoly_Waterbody = 27;

var aerialURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/CurrentImagery/MapServer";
var aerialZoomURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/1_564_Dynamic/MapServer";

var customExtentAndSR = new esri.geometry.Extent(2380210.76526192, 109581.35051693, 2582107.45873931, 404235.534501359, new esri.SpatialReference({ "wkid": 2926 }));
var countyLayer = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
var aerialLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(aerialURL, {
    id: "aerialLayer",
    visible: false
});

var pointsURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/PublicWorks/PublicWorksQueriesPoints/MapServer";
var linesURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/PublicWorks/PublicWorksQueriesLines/MapServer";
var polygonsURL = "http://igis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/PublicWorks/PublicWorksQueriesPolygons/MapServer";

var aerialLayerZoom = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(aerialZoomURL, {
    id: "aerialLayerZoom",
    visible: false
});

var tilesLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(" http://gis.spokanecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/Engineering/SectionMosaic/MapServer", {
    //var tilesLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://GISMO3.spokanecounty.org:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Engineering/SectionMosaic/MapServer", {
    id: "tilesLayer",
    visible: false
});

pointsLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(pointsURL, {
    id: "pointsLayer",
    visible: true
});
linesLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(linesURL, {
    id: "linesLayer",
    visible: true
});
polygonsLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(polygonsURL, {
    id: "polygonsLayer",
    visible: true
});

var connects;
var refPtsLyr = 11;
var parcelslLyr = 53;
var aerialLayerInfoID = 91;
var aerialLayerInfoIDText = '"' + aerialLayerInfoID + '"';
var sectionmapsLayerInfoID = 149;
var sectionmapsLayerInfoIDText = '"' + sectionmapsLayerInfoID + '"';
var SWstructuresLayerInfoID = 128;
polygonsLayer.setImageFormat("png32");
polygonsLayer.setImageTransparency(true);

//Default values for Draw Tool
var TransVal = 1;
var MyThickness = 3;
var MyFontSize = 12;
var red = 0;
var green = 0;
var blue = 0;
var newColor = [red, green, blue, TransVal]

var myPointsLayer = "Points";
var myLinesLayer = "Lines";
var myPolygonsLayer = "Polygons";
var defaultPoints = true;
var defaultLines = true;
var defaultPolygons = true;
var myPointsArray = [];
var myLinesArray = [];
var myPolygonsArray = [];



map = new Map("map", {
    extent: customExtentAndSR
});

map.on("layers-add-result", function () {
    // test to see if sub-layers have been set as visible
    for (var j = 0; j < map.layerIds.length; j++) {
        var layer = map.getLayer(map.layerIds[j]);
        alert(layer.id + ' ' + layer.opacity + ' ' + layer.visible + ' ' + layer.visibleLayers);
    }
    // add legend
    legendDijit = new Legend({
        map: map,
        layerInfos: [{
            layer: polygonsLayer,
            hideLayers: [indexPoly_CountyBdry, indexPoly_MuniBdry],
            title: " ",
            respectCurrentMapScale: true
        },
        {
            layer: linesLayer,
            hideLayers: [indexLine_PriorityArray],
            title: " ",
            respectCurrentMapScale: true
        },
        {
            layer: pointsLayer,
            hideLayers: [indexPoint_ControlPts, indexPoint_FiberPts, indexPoint_ReferencePts, indexPoint_SchoolBusStopsOSPI],
            title: " ",
            respectCurrentMapScale: true
        }]
    }, "legendDiv");
    legendDijit.startup();
});

map.on("extent-change", function () {
    //alert("visible layers for points = " + pointsLayer.visibleLayers);
    var tempArray1, tempArray2, tempArray3 = [];
    tempArray1 = (getVisibleLayersPoints());
    if (tempArray1.length) {
        pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers(tempArray1);
    }                   
    tempArray2 = (getVisibleLayersLines());
    if (tempArray2.length) {
        linesLayer.setVisibleLayers(tempArray2);
    }
    tempArray3 = (getVisibleLayersPolygons());
    if (tempArray3.length) {
        polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers(tempArray3);
    }
    $('#divScale').text("Scale: " +  number.format(map.getScale(), { places: 0 }));
});

map.on("load", function () {

    //home button
    var home = new HomeButton({
        map: map
    }, "HomeButton");
    home.startup();

    //scalebar
    var scalebar = new Scalebar({
        map: map
    });

    toolbar = new Draw(map);
    toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
    //toolbar.on("draw-complete", addMeas);
    editToolbar = new Edit(map);
    map.on("click", function (evt) {
        editToolbar.deactivate();
    });
    createMapMenu();
    createGraphicsMenu();
    map.reposition();
    map.resize();

    buildLayerList();
    firstPrint();
    // set up identify task click event
    connects = on(map, "click", executeIdentifyTask);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RPWebService.asmx/GetFCLayerProfileVisibleLayers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{"servicelayer":"' + myPointsLayer + '"}',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            if (obj == "Points NoResults;No Results Found") {
                defaultPoints = true;
                myPointsArray = [defaultVisiblePoints];
                pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePoints]);
            }
            else {
                defaultPoints = false;
                myPointsArray = [obj];
                pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([obj]);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Unable to load Map Profile: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
            myPointsArray = [defaultVisiblePoints];
            pointsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePoints]);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RPWebService.asmx/GetFCLayerProfileVisibleLayers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{"servicelayer":"' + myLinesLayer + '"}',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            if (obj == "Lines NoResults;No Results Found") {
                defaultLines = true;
                myLinesArray = [defaultVisibleLines];
                linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisibleLines]);
            }
            else {
                defaultLines = false;
                myLinesArray = [obj];
                linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([obj]);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Unable to load Map Profile: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
            defaultLines = true;
            myLinesArray = [defaultVisibleLines];
            linesLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisibleLines]);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RPWebService.asmx/GetFCLayerProfileVisibleLayers",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{"servicelayer":"' + myPolygonsLayer + '"}',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            if (obj == "Polygons NoResults;No Results Found") {
                defaultPolygons = true;
                myPolygonsArray = [defaultVisiblePolygons];
                polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePolygons]);
            }
            else {
                defaultPolygons = true;
                myPolygonsArray = [obj];
                polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([obj]);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Unable to load Map Profile: ' + data.status + ' ' + data.statusText);
            defaultPolygons = true;
            myPolygonsArray = [defaultVisiblePolygons];
            polygonsLayer.setVisibleLayers([defaultVisiblePolygons]);
        }
    });

    map.addLayers([aerialLayer, aerialLayerZoom, tilesLayer, polygonsLayer, linesLayer, pointsLayer]);

});
```